# Extra padding in TabControl tab header text

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

I want to make a custom TabControl but there is some problem with the tab header text. For some reason when I set styles for the custom paint: ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.UserPaint there appears to be extra padding after the text in the tab header.
[image: You can see that there is extra padding after the tab text.]

For the short tab text, the padding is fine. The problem is for the longer ones. How to remove this extra padding? The padding of the TabControl is set to 0.

Here is my code:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class NewTabControl : TabControl
{
  public NewTabControl()
  {
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.UserPaint |
             ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer,
             true);
    DoubleBuffered = true;
  }

  protected override void CreateHandle()
  {
    base.CreateHandle();
    Alignment = TabAlignment.Top;
  }

  protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
  {
    var g = e.Graphics;
    var Drawer = g;

    Drawer.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
    Drawer.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
    Drawer.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.SystemDefault;
    Drawer.Clear(Color.Gainsboro);

    for (var i = 0; i <= TabCount - 1; i++)
    {
      var Header = new Rectangle(new Point(GetTabRect(i).Location.X + 2, 
                                 GetTabRect(i).Location.Y),
                                 new Size(GetTabRect(i).Width, GetTabRect(i).Height));
      var HeaderSize = new Rectangle(Header.Location, new Size(Header.Width, Header.Height));

      if (i == SelectedIndex)
      {
        Drawer.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Gainsboro), HeaderSize);

        Drawer.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.White),
                             new Rectangle(Header.X - 5, Header.Y - 3, Header.Width, Header.Height + 5));

        Drawer.DrawString(TabPages[i].Text, Font,
                          new SolidBrush(Color.Black),
                          new Rectangle(Header.Location, new Size(Header.Width, Header.Height)));

      }
      else
      {
        Drawer.DrawString(TabPages[i].Text, Font,
                          new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new Rectangle(Header.Location, new Size(Header.Width, Header.Height)));
      }
    }

    Drawer.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.WhiteSmoke), new Rectangle(0, 20, Width - 80, Height - 20));

    Drawer.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.WhiteSmoke, 2), new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height));
    Drawer.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the `SizeMode` ?

Comment: There isn't an available method to change the tab width of an individual tab.  You aren't centering the text, so it looks worse than a normal tab drawing.  Do prefer the TextRenderer method over DrawString: `TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, TabPages[i].Text, this.Font, Header, Color.Black, TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter);`

Comment: _There isn't an available method to change the tab width of an individual tab._ Well one can pad with space glyphs